# String Replace Regex, Whitespace in the Beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace the whitespace in the beginning of the string?

```
insertItem = insertItem.replace(/\A\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0yvn0w0/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript won't support `\A`,instead you need to use `^`  anchor. And also `g` modifier is unnecessary here since replacement occurs once for each line.

```
insertItem.replace(/^\s+/m, '').toLowerCase();
```